# Executing postgresql psql \timing with subprocess

Tags: python, postgresql

When executing the \timing command with a query from psql with python, using subprocess the \t keeps getting removed/substituted.

The SQL I'm trying to execute is

```
sql = """\\timing
        select count(*) from mytable;"""
```

Comment: Don't execute external subprocess. It's more reliable and faster to use native python postgres client, and measure query execution time using functions from `time`, `timeit` or `datetime` modules.

Answer (score 0):

\t will be seen as a escaped character.
thus the the "t" will be removed from the string.

What you want to do is:

```
sql = r"""\timing select count(*) from mytable;"""
```

The r before the quotes will make the string literal and will keep all characters in the string.

You could also use \\ to escape the \.

```
sql = """\\timing select count(*) from mytable;"""
```

Comment: When I do it that way the \t is still being removed.

sql = r"""\timing
        select count(*) from mytable;"""

r = subprocess.run('psql -h %s  -U %s -d %s -At -c %s' % (args.hostname,args.username,args.db,sql), stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)

Comment: Do you really need to use subprocesses? I think using an postgresql-python module like  psycopg is easier to implement.

Comment: The \timing gives the most accurate time for the query execution.  the time/timeit won't work.

Comment: \timing is a toggle, maybe you can use EXPLAIN ANALYZE in your query? "EXPLAIN ANALYZE select count(*) from mytable;"